# When using Pylint, how to state a particular list of variables which are valid names with the pyproject.toml settings file

Tags: python, pylint, pyproject.toml

Running pylint on a file containing variables such as `x` or `l` will raise an error, though these variables might be meaningful in the context that they're in.

I could disable all such errors by adding the following to `pyproject.toml`:

```yaml
[tool.pylint."MESSAGES CONTROL"]
disable = [ "invalid-name"]
```

But I would prefer to be able to instead explicitly state the variables that I would like to ignore.

Comment: See the docs on how to disable messages locally: https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/faq.html#is-it-possible-to-locally-disable-a-particular-message

Comment: @KlausD. I don't want add a `#pylint: ...` whenever I want to use `x` as a variable though, I would like to be able to add a list of exceptions to `pyproject.toml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To ignore pylint errors for particular variable names the `good-names` list can be set within `pyproject.toml` as follows:

```
[tool.pylint."MESSAGES CONTROL"]
good-names = [
    "x",
    "y",
]
```

Which will make `x` and `y` valid variable names for pylint.

Answer (score 11):

While searching for the same issue, I found https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/3181#issuecomment-624284441, which explains that square braces cannot be used. Rather, a comma separated list of values, wrapped in quotes will work:

```
[tool.pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']
max-line-length = 120
disable = "too-many-arguments,not-callable"
```

Or, triple-quotes can be used for readability with many disable statements:

```
[tool.pylint.'MESSAGES CONTROL']
max-line-length = 120
disable = """
    too-many-arguments,
    not-callable
"""
```

Comment: Thanks - this is useful but not the answer to the question - the question is to use `good-names`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73082392/3130747

Comment: Also - you can use a list in the `disable = ...` instead of a multiline string, which I personally prefer.